# tesseract command not working from command line in windows

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I installed tesseract-OCR for windows and it resides in C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR path in my system.

I set up an environment variable by adding C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR in the PATH variable.

I also set up TESSDATA_PREFIX in system variable to the same above tesseract location.

Still, when I try to run the command "tesseract some path\image.tif somepath\output", it gives message as "'tesseract' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

when i run the same command from the location where tesseract is installed, it works fine but i need to have it set in the environment variables as it will also allow PYOCR wrapper to recognise it.

PYOCR is currently giving "pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]" as empty list.

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my answer is a little bit late, but I will give my setup that seems to work from few minutes. As you, I was using PYOCR library, and at the beginning I get an empty list when using  `pyocr.get_available_tools()`.

I'm running it on a Windows 10 laptop.

First, I installed **Tesseract** in version 4 in alpha from here:
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki and then added location in my windows user PATH variable. From here, run a new command line and check that `tesseract` tool is detected, if not you're environmment is not properly configured!

Then, I installed **PyOCR** using a simple `pip pyocr` and use the follow imports
before using pyocr functions:

```
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
```

EDIT:
I've look in current source files of PYOCR and I've found this:

```
def is_available():
    _set_environment()
    return util.is_on_path(TESSERACT_CMD)
```

PyOCR is just  looking for tesseract.exe in your os Path variable, so I think you just have to solve the mention issue and it will work.

EDIT 2:
I updated the download link with UB Mannheim version. Seems more efficient on my data. Also, I downgraded to Tesseract 3, because a lot of flags was not supported in 4.0 alpha build.

Hope it can help a little bit,
Best regards

Comment: In your answer you assume that after installing tesseract one would be able to run tesseract from command line, but in the original question person is already unable to do that for some reason even though he set PATH variable and did basically everything you did.

Comment: Hi Dmitrii, As Abhilash Kumar said, he seems that Tesseract is not recognized by his command line tool => Still, when I try to run [...] external command". I just try to give the basics steps that help PyOCR to recognize Tesseract in my setup. Sometimes you try a lot of things and ommit simple things. Not sure that will solve his problem.
EDIT: Look at my edit, I think the Path env var will solve his issue

Answer (score -1):

Please check the correct path of installation of Tesseract-OCR. Setting the correct path, i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR` worked for me.